# pycodestyle: Ignore directives project-wise

Tags: python, pep8, pycodestyle

Is there a way to configure a python project to ignore specific `pycodestyle` directives project-wise?

i.e. adding a file in the likes of say `.pycodeignore` in the project's root with entries like:

```
E302
E266
```

etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [configuration docs](http://pycodestyle.pycqa.org/en/latest/intro.html#configuration), you can create a file called `setup.cfg` or `tox.ini` in the root of your project and write the following:

```
[pycodestyle]
ignore = E226,E302
```

Answer (score 3):

As per the `pycodestyle` documentation

```
[pycodestyle]
count = False
ignore = E226,E302,E41
max-line-length = 160
statistics = True
```

At the project level, a `setup.cfg` file or a `tox.ini` file is read if present. If none of these files have a `[pycodestyle]` section, no project specific configuration is loaded.